# Fuelphp ORM related limit ignored

Tags: php, fuelphp

I ran in to a problem what i never experienced with fuelphp.

On the users profile page i allow other users to leave comments.
And when i use `related comments limit` in my controller function its just ignored.

Code

```
public function action_view($id)
    {

        $user = Model_User::find($id, array(
                'related' => array(
                    'comments' => array(
                        'order_by' => array(
                            array('id', 'DESC'),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                 'limit' => 5,
            ));

        if(empty($user)):
            Response::redirect(Uri::base() . "welcome/404");
        endif;

        $this->template->title = $user->username . "'s Profile | " . Config::get('site_name');
        $this->template->content = View::forge('user/profile', array('user' => $user));
    }
```

The `order_by` works like a charm, but the limit doesnt, it still lists all the comments.
Tryed multiple variations got lot of different weird errors.

Comment: Can you enable "Profiling" from che config? So you can view the entire query created an we can analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've found this part of the docs, it should help you: [troubleshooting](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/intro.html#/troubleshooting)

Try to put the "limit" in the properties array: in the current position the "limit" limit the number of user, but you are retrieving a single user so it doesn't work.

Try with this:

```
$user = Model_User::find($id, array(
    'related' => array(
        'comments' => array(
            'order_by' => array(
                array('id', 'DESC'),
            ),
            'limit' => 5,
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, yes i tried that one too, it ignores the limit, order_by is fine but the limit is ignored

Comment: try with "rows_limit" instead of "limit", as it was descrived in the link on the first line

Comment: belive it or not i tried that too, thats ignored either, i totally lost the line now with this

Comment: Very strange, perhaps it is a framework bug... I'll investigate as soon as possible

Comment: One of the author of the framework gave a similar answer here: http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/11528/orm-related-limit-ignored#Item_4 . Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that this query runs a find by value. This type of find runs a get_one(), and is always limited by 1.

So your limit isn't ignored, it's overwritten by the fact that you use this type of find().

To do what you want:

```
$user = Model_User::query()
    ->where('id', '=', $id)
    ->related('comments')
    ->order_by('comments.id', 'DESC')
    ->rows_limit(5)
    ->get();
```