# Fuelphp related limit

Tags: php, mysql, limit, fuelphp

I am currenty working on a story board, and i upload images there telling a story.

So the problem is i just want to limit the related query.

The story board has a `has_many`relation for images. and on the list where the story boards appear i just only want to show the first image, and when someone clicks it it will show all, the show all is fine, but i can limit just the related images in my view.

And im totally confused with it because i read lot of infos about it in the forum, tried may variations, the limit is just ignored, or i get errors

so here is my code

controller

```
$stories = Model_Storyboard::find('all', array('related' => array('storyboardimage')));

$this->template->title = "Sotry Board | " . Config::get('site_name');
$this->template->content = View::forge('storyboard/index', array('stories' => $stories));
```

So how can i limit the `storyboardimage` to show the first image for each storyboard?

Sorry if im askin to much, but i would be really happy if someone could give me a working example beacuse i tried lots of variations and nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

You can add criteria onto the relations, i.e. `where`, `order_by`, `limit` etc.

For example (note this is untested)

```
$stories = Model_Storyboard::find('all', array(
    'related' => array(
        'storyboardimage'   =>  array(
            'limit' =>  1,
            'order_by'  =>  array(
                'field_indicative_of_first_image' => 'desc'
            ),
        )
    )
));
```

In the example above I've added in `field_indicative_of_first_image` which simply means replace this with a column which you can use to get the first image. This might be for example a `created_at` column or a `weight` or `sort_order` column. Without knowing your database schema, I can't tell you which you'd need.

Comment: thanks for your reply but its the same, i get all the images back insted of just one, im totally clusess with this, no matter how i do, no matter what i do, the limit is always ignored

Comment: Try changing `limit` to `rows_limit`

Comment: This question demonstrates a similar problem with a similar solution which has been accepted. Perhaps you're implementing it incorrectly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399884/fuelphp-orm-related-limit-ignored